# Touches to UIScrollView subviews outside the clipping bounds

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit

I am making a swiftUI app. I have some scrollable content for which I am using UIScrollView (Not using SwiftUI ScrollView due to some limitations). I have embedded my UIScrollView in a VStack. Above UIScrollView inside VStack I have a swiftUI view which has a tap gesture. My UIScrollView subview also has a tap gesture and UIScrollView subview can scroll over SwiftUI view inside VStack.

Problem:
When I scroll up and UIScrollView covers the SwiftUI View I can not tap on the portion of subview which is outside of the clipping bounds of UIScrollView, My SwiftUI View gets tapped instead, even when its not visible.

I have attached my sample code and some Images.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Code:
UIScrollViewWrapper

```
struct UIScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        let child = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        child.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        context.coordinator.hostingController = child
        scrollView.addSubview(child.view)
        
        let newSize = child.view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: height))
        child.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
        
        scrollView.contentSize = newSize
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.hostingController?.rootView = content()
        
        if let child = context.coordinator.hostingController {
            let newSize = child.view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: height))
            child.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
            
            scrollView.contentSize = newSize
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: UIScrollViewWrapper
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>!
        
        init(_ parent: UIScrollViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(.cyan)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("SwiftUI View")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    )
                    .frame(height: 75)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("SwiftUI")
                    }
                
                UIScrollViewWrapper(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height - 75) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(.mint)
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 2)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("UIScrollView")
                        }
                        
                }
                .border(.red, width: 2)
                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Things I have tried:

I tried making UIScrollView fullscreen and offsetting the subview so my SwiftUI view is visible. If I do this touches to my SwiftUI view gets blocked by UIScrollView. With this approach I have tried changing the zIndex of SwiftUI View putting it on top of UIScrollView when necessary but this is not working with my animations and giving bad user experience.

[image: 3]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(.cyan)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("SwiftUI View")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    )
                    .frame(height: 75)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("SwiftUI")
                    }
                
                UIScrollViewWrapper(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(.mint)
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 2)
                        .offset(y: 75)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("UIScrollView")
                        }
                        
                }
                .border(.red, width: 2)
                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me solve this problem ?
Thank You !

Comment: When you set `.clipsToBounds = false` on a `UIScrollView` (or any other view), that view's subviews can be **seen** outside the bounds, but not **interacted** with. I could give you a UIKit solution, but not sure how to accomplish this with SwiftUI

Comment: can you share your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To do this with UIKit...

- constrain the scroll view to fill the screen (safe area)
- constrain the "sticky top view" to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide**
- constrain the "scrollable content view" to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide**

This will keep the top view "stuck in place" while allowing the content view to scroll normally.

Quick example:

```
class StickyTopScrollView: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        let stickyTopView = UIView()
        let contentView = UIView()

        // label to add to the sticky top view
        let stvLabel = UILabel()
        stvLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 26, weight: .light)
        stvLabel.textAlignment = .center
        stvLabel.textColor = .white
        stvLabel.text = "Sticky Top View"
        
        // vertical stack view to add to the "scrollable content" view
        //  to which we'll add some labels
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 32
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        stickyTopView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        [scrollView, stickyTopView, contentView, stvLabel, stackView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        stickyTopView.addSubview(stvLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stickyTopView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        let topViewHeight: CGFloat = 75.0
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // scroll view fills the safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // center label in stick top view
            stvLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stickyTopView.centerXAnchor),
            stvLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stickyTopView.centerYAnchor),
            
            // sticky top view should be full width and "stuck" to the top of the
            //  scroll view Frame Layout Guide
            stickyTopView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stickyTopView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stickyTopView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stickyTopView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topViewHeight),
            
            // constrain "scrollable content" view to Content Layout Guide
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: topViewHeight),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain "scrollable content" view Width to Frame Layout Guide
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain stack view in "scrollable content" view with
            //  20-points "padding" on all 4 sides
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        ])
        
        // now, let's add some labels to the stack view so our
        //  "scrollable content" view will be tall enough to need to scroll
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 26, weight: .light)
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        // a little styling
        stickyTopView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        
        // and add tap gesture recognizers
        stickyTopView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(stickyTopTapped(_:))))
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scrollContentTapped(_:))))
    }
    
    @objc func stickyTopTapped(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Sticky Top View Tapped")
    }

    @objc func scrollContentTapped(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Scrollable Content View Tapped")
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this when running and scrolling:

[image]

[image]

[image]

While the "sticky top view" is visible, it can be tapped. As we "cover" it with the scrollable content view, the content view will get the tap.

You may be able to adapt that to SwiftUI with a `UIScrollView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` object.